# Cross Database Query between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, query, azure-sql-database

Can we built a Cross database query for Insert, Update and Delete between SQL Server and Azure SQL DB and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In fact, a traditional cross database query isn't possible. You can set up a mechanism for querying between two Azure SQL Databases, but it's not the traditional mechanism. I have a [blog post on how that works](https://www.scarydba.com/2016/03/21/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/) and there are links there to the documentation. However, even with that, you can't combine it to a query with on-premises SQL Server.

Comment: You can go _from_ SQL Server to Azure SQL Database with Linked Server.  And From Azure SQL Database Managed Instance to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database with Linked Server.  But between Azure SQL Databases you must use Elastic Database Query.